# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string error isn't always shown in similar cases

Tags: java, database, oracle, date

I have a `select` SQL query which contains this:

```
to_date('292278994-08-17 08:12:55.807', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
```

The value of this date was generated with this java code line:

```
Date maxDate = new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

It is obvious that year 292278994 doesn't match 'yyyy'.
The problem: running my query causes

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

on the main database but not on the backup database. The databases are fully equivalent, the backup is of course the copy of the main one. Both of them are an Oracle 11.2.
I guess it depends on some configuration but I couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know the cause of this?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that the following gives error on one database but not the other?  SELECT to_date('292278994-08-17 08:12:55.807', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') FROM DUAL;    If so - what is the output for the database which gives no error?  ETA: if not, are you running your select statement on both instances in a way that spools out ALL results?  It may be that you're using a tool that just pulls 100 records, and first 100 records found on main DB don't have this issue, but first 100 records on backup do.

Comment: Actually I have a bit longer SELECT query. The one which doesn't give any error returns with null record.

Comment: Your response was ambiguous.  Did you run this in both databases?  SELECT to_date('292278994-08-17 08:12:55.807', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') FROM DUAL;  Can you confirm it gives error in one but not the other?

Comment: Sorry. I ran that on both, got the error every time.

Comment: I had a similar issue on a single database when I ran a procedure that contained an unclear format in TO_DATE; When used SQL Navigator it was fine, but via a C# application I got the same error.
Anyway, your request is a bit odd. What exactly are you trying to achieve using MAX_VALUE?

Comment: Not sure. This was written by an ex colleague years ago. Recently an other colleague tried to use this piece of code and ran into this problem. I got the job to examine this. I told him to simply use 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999 or an even lower date instead, as it won't really matter in the lifetime of our software. He does so but wanted to know the reason.

Comment: Okay - that resolves the sanity check  - See Patrick's answer below.  The TO_DATE() function is always invalid, but one database is likely getting an execution plan which filters out bad records before it tries to evaluate TO_DATE() on the problematic column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the explain plans of your actual query as it looks like you've got different plans and one is "short circuiting" the conditions; it doesn't actually get around to looking at the date format.

Here's what I mean:

```
select *
from dual
where 1=0
AND sysdate < to_date('292278994-08-17 08:12:55.807', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
```

vs

```
select *
from dual
where 1=0
OR sysdate < to_date('292278994-08-17 08:12:55.807', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
```

The first query above will return 0 rows and will not report an error (at least it doesn't for me), yet the second one does. That's because the database can evaluate the 1=0 (false) first and doesn't need to check the second condition  at all because FALSE AND (TRUE or FALSE) is always false whereas with an OR, it's possible that the second condition returns TRUE and the WHERE clause returns a TRUE result.

For anyone interested, in the plan of the first query, I get this:

```
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL AND SYSDATE@!<TO_DATE('292278994-08-17 
              08:12:55.807','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss'))
```

(Note that it's not 1=0 anymore but rather NULL IS NOT NULL)

and in the second one, it knows the 1=0 can be omitted entirely:

```
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(SYSDATE@!<TO_DATE('292278994-08-17 
              08:12:55.807','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show the parameters that could affect the dates. try this on both databases and compare

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

Comment: The result is DD-MON-RR on both.